# Docker without docker

Tags: docker, benchmarking, intel, intel-pin

I am trying to execute some docker containers, without docker itself !!!

Maybe you know `CloudSuite Benchmarks`. I am trying to run the [MediaStreaming](http://cloudsuite.ch/mediastreaming/) one without the Docker (I need the executables and not the containers, because I have to run them via an intel pintool that uses executables)

I used the `export` instruction like that:

`docker export streaming_server > server.tar.gz`

then I unzipped the tar files. I am not sure, what should I do on the next step. As you can see on the link, things are getting tricky. I have to execute something like that:

`docker run -d --name streaming_server --volumes-from streaming_dataset --net streaming_network cloudsuite/media-streaming:server`

Any ideas how to do it? I did try it first on `hello-wolrd` but things were more easy, after the unzip, I had just an executable, now I am not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/ParsaLab/cloudsuite/blob/master/benchmarks/media-streaming/server/Dockerfile, looks like it runs nginx...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you don't have to extract the docker images, the source is just located over here: https://github.com/ParsaLab/cloudsuite/tree/master/benchmarks/media-streaming